# Dynamic Component Loader vs. Lazy Loading

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

What is the difference between `Dynamic Component Loader` and `Lazy Loading`? I need to build an application that needs to have an `<router-outlet>` at the root of the application. My Problem is that I don't know how to implement a Component that renders Child-Components according to data, dynamically. My current approach builds up on `Dynamic Component Loader`, but using this technique I have issues concerning tracking my location, navigate back, etc. 
Is there any best practice for using "multiple `<router-outlets>`" (e.g. Lazy Loading)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading components dynamically is not related to Lazy Loading.

Lazy Loading is a way to split up your application into modules that are loaded lazily (in the background) instead of loading your entire application at the start. This helps your app load more quickly so the first page is rendered sooner than it would if you did not use lazy loading.

For example, you might have a settings menu which loads various settings, but you don't expect users to visit that menu very often, so you put all the components for settings into a module and then you set that module to be loaded lazily (in other words none of that code needs to be downloaded unless a user actually visits the `/settings` route).

All angular applications must have a `<router-outlet>` at the base component (usually AppComponent). This is a requirement of all Angular applications.

You may want to consider also using auxiliary routes - these are optional, and allow you to load components in different 'places'. You can read about them [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/aux-routes.html)

Alternatively you can (for simple cases) just use ngIf, like this:

/app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isOption1(); else Option2">
  <my-option1-component></my-option1-component>
</div>
<ng-template #Option2>
  <my-option2-component></my-option2-component>
</ng-template>
```

/app.component.ts

```
public isOption1: boolean {
  return <some test that returns true or false>;
}
```

So based on the logic the method isOption1 returns, the user will see either Option1 component (when true) or the Option2 component (when false).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So Lazy Loading is only interesting in terms of performance? I think `auxiliary routes` is what I'm looking for - but is there any possibility to display the routes "normal looking"?

Comment: Yes lazy loading is only for performance. You can use the simple method I showed, but auxillary routes is a better solution to your problem. I do not understand what you mean by 'display routes "normal looking?"'  Routes are routes and appear in the address bar /page1/details page2/details /page3/summary - they are whatever you define them to be.

Comment: Ok sounds great :) I did some research and ended up with [this Website](https://yakovfain.com/2016/08/16/angular-2-working-with-auxiliary-routes/). But this route/url was not very good looking - hence, my question.

Comment: Auxillary routes are always displayed in parathensis, so you cannot avoid that. If you don't want that then you have to use the ngIf idea I showed in my answer. The # is not needed in the url for angular anymore. If my answer is correct, please mark it so. Thanks.

Comment: All right - thank you :) Sorry I'm quite new to Stackoverflow :/